# How To Render Two or More Bokeh Plots In HTML with Div and Script Tag?

Tags: python, django, plot, bokeh

I want To Plot Two or More Graph in HTML using Div and script Tag, But It Plots Only last one.

Am working on Django

```
   plot code.....
   script , divi = components(plot)
   plot1 = figure()
   plot1.circle([1,2], [3,4])
   script , pie = components(plot1)
   return render(request,'result.html',{'company':fetch,'tabcontent':temp,'pie':pie,'last_20':last_20f,'divi':divi,'script':script})
```

```
 some code...
 <div class="graph1">
    {{divi | safe}}
 </div>
 <div class="last_20">
    {{last_20|safe}}
 </div>
 <div class="pie_area">
    {{pie | safe}}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naming the script tag differently worked and In the End of Body tag add {{script|safe}} and {{scriptxyz | safe}}

```
   plot code.....
   script , divi = components(plot)
   plot1 = figure()
   plot1.circle([1,2], [3,4])
   script1 , pie = components(plot1)
   return render(request,'result.html', {'company':fetch,'tabcontent':temp,'pie':pie,'last_20':last_20f,'divi':divi,'script':script,'script1':script1})
```

```
 <div class="graph1">
    {{divi | safe}}
 </div>
 <div class="last_20">
    {{last_20|safe}}
 </div>
 <div class="pie_area">
    {{pie | safe}}
 </div>
```

```
 {{script | safe}}
 {{script1 | safe}}
```

Comment: It's possible to accomplish this with one call to `components` and one script, see the documentation https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#components

Comment: @bigreddot Yes! That's Much Better